# Write file data directly to a property in my class

Tags: database, vb.net, file, file-upload

I have a class that I use to send file data to and from my database, My question is. How do I write file data directly to a property in my class without first saving the data to a memoryStream. Would there be an advantage to doing this?

```
Class Rif
    Public Property fileData As Stream
End Class

    Dim rif = New Rif
    Dim buf As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}

    Using stream As Stream = myResp.GetResponseStream()
        rif.fileData = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024)
            Dim count As Integer
            Do
                count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024)
                rif.fileData.Write(buf, 0, count)
            Loop While stream.CanRead AndAlso count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like, You already have the proper method.

There may be a option to use pipes, too. 
But perhaps this is to much effort and gives no gain in performance.

So for me it looks like You have already used the common , and recommended technique.

Best regards

Comment: I am getting an error in this line "rif.fileData = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024) "Value of type integer can not be converted to stream"

Comment: what does stream.Read return ?
Please be aware of the documentation.
Read returns read bytes and buff is the destination, which will keep the data